# ffmpeg - Convert MP4 to WebM, poor results

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to encode a video to webm for playing through a HTML5 video tag.  I have these settings...

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:a 128k -b:v 1M -c:a libopus output.webm
```

The results aren't great, video has lost lot's of it's sharpness.  Looking at the original file I can see the bitrate is 1694kb/s.

Are there any settings I can add or change to improve the output? Would maybe a 2 pass encode improve things?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/270625/how-to-fast-convert-mp4-to-webm-using-ffmpeg

Comment: Related: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/19590/convert-mp4-to-webm-without-quality-loss-with-ffmpeg

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Try with

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 30 -b:v 0 -b:a 128k -c:a libopus output.webm
```

Adjust the CRF value till the quality/size tradeoff is ok. Lower values produce bigger but better files.

Comment: `-crf` range mentioned at: https://superuser.com/questions/677576/what-is-crf-used-for-in-ffmpeg

Comment: When I tried this, I got a severe degradation in audio quality.

Comment: @BenCrowell You may want to increase `-b:a 128k`. This is the audio bitrate.

Comment: This works great! A question: what does it mean to set video bitrate to 0 (`-b:v 0`)? It's been impossible to find the documentation for this option in https://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html

Comment: The vpx encoders use b:v value as a max bitrate threshold when using crf.

Comment: @ack_inc It's needed to trigger the [Constant quality mode](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9#constantq), quote from it: "Note that `-b:v` MUST be 0"

Comment: It says "deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly"

Comment: ```ffmpeg  -i input.mp4  -lossless 1  output.webm``` I saw this in another answer, I wonder if it would have the same effect as this answer, perhaps even better?

Answer (score 9):

Try to run two passes:

```
ffmpeg  -i file.mp4  -b:v 0  -crf 30  -pass 1  -an -f webm -y /dev/null

ffmpeg  -i file.mp4  -b:v 0  -crf 30  -pass 2  output.webm
```

From - https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9

Comment: Thanks for that really excellent link!. Highly relevant to know how to trade off between quality, speed and file size